# restrict delete of a referenced managedobject

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity, cascading-deletes

I have a simple Core Data model:

Entity Team (name, logo)
Entity Sport (name, teams to->many Teams)

So, a Sport can have many Teams

I create the Team first, then add or edit a Sport and add the Teams.
If I delete a Team, my app starts crashing.
I believe because it is looking for the deleted reference.

So, how can I restrict via Core Data, not to delete an Entity which is being used as reference from another Entity's relation.

I don't want to set the relationship to nil. And I don't want to go and delete the Team from the Sport first, and then delete it alone. I just want it to notify that I can't delete it. i.e. I'm looking for a built-in checker.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up on Core Data's "Relationship Delete Rules", if you haven't already. And you want to make sure that your Team <<---> Sport relationship is bidirectional.

Alternatively, instead of calling the generated removeXxxObject and removeXxxs methods directly, you may want to implement wrapper methods that do necessary checking *before* calling 'remove' methods.

Comment: Why is bidirectional important?

Comment: I found that things don't work as well with unidirectional relationships, though in one case that is what I need - so that's what I have and it's fine. I think that Core Data does a better job of maintaining model integrity when relationships are bidirectional. It may come down to simply having delete rules (even default ones) to work with during deletions. If you get a chance, check out Marcus Zarra's Core Data book; page 13 addresses this issue.